# Transforming date string from one timezone to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have spent several hours trying to figure out how JavaScript works with dates. I have come across this question, but it does not seem to asnwer my specific question.

My input is a string like this:

```
"2018-02-19T07:00:00Z"
```

My goal is to transform this into a datetime which would differ from the original date by 4 hours - WITHOUT ANY TIMEZONE (!):

```
"2018-02-19T11:00:00Z"
```

Is it possible in JavaScript ?

Comment: I write this in a comment because it's not a vanilla javascript solution, but you should check [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: `WITHOUT ANY TIMEZONE (!)` WHAT DO YOU MEAN (?)

Comment: I mean, `2018-02-19T011:00:00Z`, not `2018-02-19T07:00:00Z + 04.00`

Comment: Hint: [`Z` actually is a timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) :-)

Comment: Like @Bergi said, you are actually manipulating a timezone. Your final String will contain one aswell.

Comment: Just use `var d = new Date(str); d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours()+4); return d.toISOString()`

Comment: `T011` is a mistake, that's not valid ISO, since there's only 2 hour digits it would just be `T11`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out all the functions relating to "UTC" and "ISO" on the [Date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
var input = "2018-02-19T07:00:00Z";
var t = new Date(input);
t.setUTCHours(t.getUTCHours()+4)
var iso = t.toISOString().replace(/\.\d+/,'');
console.log(iso);
```

*(I added a little regex to get rid of the milliseconds so it matches your expected output, you can remove that if the miliseconds don't matter, it's valid ISO either way.)*

It's 4 lines of code, you do not need a library.

Comment: For me it does not work. It yields `2018-02-19T15:00:00Z`. Apparently, it's because my local timezone is also +4 GMT. So the logic is like 15 = 7 + 4 + 4.

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan - You're telling me that when you hit the "run code snippet" button it shows `2018-02-19T15:00:00Z`? I'm not sure how that's possible since this code uses UTC time, which has nothing to do with your timezone. This code should give the same result no matter what your timezone is.

Comment: No, I am telling that in my JS code it shows 15 instead of 11

Comment: then your code is different than mine. if you use the code i gave you then in doesn't matter where in the world you are.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Occam'sRazor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48930746/3660134) answer, you could also do it without using the `Date` object, by using some String manipulations :

```js
var str = "2018-02-19T07:00:00Z";
var timeZoneHours = +str.split('-').pop().split(':')[0].split('T').pop() + 4;
console.log(timeZoneHours);

str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(':') -2) + (timeZoneHours < 10 ? '0' + timeZoneHours.toString() : timeZoneHours.toString()) + str.substring(str.indexOf(':'), str.length);
console.log(str);
```